# I cannot load people picker sppeoplepicker.js on publishing page it's working SitePages

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jquery-plugins, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

[People picker function is not working when publishing a page in SP2013 (Publishing site).  Can any one guide me with some solution ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o3dL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution when i published that page need to add two references
1.
2.